# buildozer kivy python: TypeError: read() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, python-2.x, kivy

После выполнения команды:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

`Buildozer` выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                   
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>        
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.38.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py",     line 13, in main                                                               
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])                      
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line      122, in __init__                                                                 
    self.config.read(filename, "utf-8")                              
TypeError: read() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это уже известная разработчикам `buildozer` ошибка: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/793

Дождитесь (или сами подправьте тот файл) пока исправят, например тут уже есть pull request с исправлением: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/pull/791

---

А насчет самой ошибки. Проблема [в этой строчке](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/blob/c66af5dc0bf7420df6d71c26bee55f085b80c93b/buildozer/__init__.py#L122):

```
self.config.read(filename, "utf-8")
```

По ошибке выходит, что метод `read` ожидал два параметра, т.е. `self` и `filename`, но получил три -- дополнительно кодировку.

`buildozer` использует модуль `configparser` в качестве конфига и если посмотреть на реализацию метода `read` в официальной документацию, то станет понятно почему ошибка произошла:

- Метод в python 2: [read(filenames)](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read)
- Метод в python 3: [read(filenames, encoding=None)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read)

---

**PS.**

Вы можете сами по-быстрому починить баг локально (для себя) в файле `buildozer/__init__.py`, например так:

```
    if exists(filename):
        try:
            self.config.read(filename, "utf-8")
        except TypeError:
            self.config.read(filename)
        self.check_configuration_tokens()
```

Но лучше дождаться исправления от разработчиков.

Comment: Большое спасиб! Благодарен!

Comment: @ДмитрийТехников, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)